# Kotlin - Replace class delegation - Multiple classes with same functionality different signature

Tags: kotlin, delegation, junit-rule

I am working with JunitRules RuleChain and Kotlin. I am new to both and have two classes that do the exact same thing, the only difference being the rule chain.

The first class looks like this :

```
class BaseActivityTestRule<T : Activity>(
    private val activityRule : ActivityRule<T>
) : TestRule by RuleChain.outerRule(CustomRuleOne).around(activityRule) {

    // do something 
}
```

I require another class that does the exact same thing as `BaseActivityTestRule` but the delegate is different.

Example :

```
class ExtendedActivityTestRule<T : Activity>(
    private val activityRule : ActivityRule<T>
) : TestRule by RuleChain.outerRule(CustomRuleOne).around(CustomRuleTwo).around(activityRule) {

    // do something 
}
```

How can I accomplish this without duplicating code blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass a boolean parameter to your constructor and use it to create the basic or extended `TestRule`:

```
fun <T> createTestRule(activityRule: ActivityRule<T>, extended: Boolean) = 
    if(extended) 
        RuleChain.outerRule(CustomRuleOne).around(CustomRuleTwo).around(activityRule)
    else
        RuleChain.outerRule(CustomRuleOne).around(activityRule)

class ActivityTestRule<T : Activity>(
    private val activityRule : ActivityRule<T>,
    extended: Boolean = false
) : TestRule by createTestRule(activityRule, extended) {

    // do something 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I ended up abstracting the functionality and creating two separate classes with different signatures that extend the abstract class.

Example :

```
abstract class BaseActivityTestRule<T : Activity>(
private val activityRule : ActivityRule<T>){  
 // Do Something 
}
```

And then extend it :

```
class ExtendedActivityTestRule<T : Activity>(
private val activityRule : ActivityRule<T>): BaseActivityTestRule<T>(activityRule), TestRule by Delegate
```

For Subsequent implementations :

```
class DifferentActivityTestRule<T : Activity>(
private val activityRule : ActivityRule<T>): BaseActivityTestRule<T>(activityRule), TestRule by SomeOtherDelegate
```